# FFT of uneven time series data in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, data-science, dft

I have a time series data say t = [1, 5, 6, 8.5, 12, 20, 21.5, 22.3, 27, 30] in seconds  and electric field at corresponding time (t) say E. Now, as you may have noticed that the time interval (dt) is not even or fixed. So, I implemented defining the FFT manually rather than calling an in-built FFT() function.

```
def DFT(x):
    """
    Function to calculate the 
    discrete Fourier Transform 
    of a 1D real-valued signal x
    """

    N = len(x)
    n = np.arange(N)
    k = n.reshape((N, 1))
    e = np.exp(-2j * np.pi * k * n / N)
    
    X = np.dot(e, x)
    
    return X
```

But, it is not working. My objective is to calculate

1. DFT of E.
2. Frequecy array corresponding to the given time array (t).

I request modestly if anyone could suggest and help me out of this complicacy.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make another series, that will be kind of interpolation based on original one. For example fit some ML model to data, then predict output on input with constant dt.
That would be something like:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor as rf
t=[1, 5, 6, 8.5, 12, 20, 21.5, 22.3, 27, 30]
E=f([1, 5, 6, 8.5, 12, 20, 21.5, 22.3, 27, 30])
model=SVR()
model.fit(t,E)
######## or
model1=rf()
model1.fit(t,E)
########
t1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7....30]
E1=model.predict(t1)
```

Then apply FFT to t1, E1

Comment: Do I need to import any packages in the code ?

Comment: You need to import package of the model- SVR, RF or others. For example from sklearn.svm import SVR or from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor